# Get constraints which are not applied due to priority?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, frame, nslayoutconstraint

I setup constraints for views with priorities. So if I change the view frame some of these constraints are ignored.

How to check programmatically if the constraint is ignored?

Checking frame is not appropriate because I need to check vertical constraint and this view appears from bottom (presented modally with default animation).

Comment: The best way in such cases is clear all constraints for the particular view and build all required constraints again.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep it in mind. I have also found out that I can't use frames in some cases when constraints are enough complex - in ```layoutSubviews``` (and similar overriden methods) the frame still may be incorrect/not applied.

Comment: yeah that is correct.